# Exercise 1.6 [Goldbach 1752] of An introduction to number theory

Tags: number-theory

Prove that  if $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ has the property that $f(n)$ is prime for all $n\ge 1$, then $f$ must be a constant.

This is a Exercise of An introduction to number theory.  In fact, I am not sure what is $\mathbb Z[x]$. Is it  integer value  function ? Besides, how to show it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let $f(1)=p$.

Show that for each $k$ you have 
$$p | f(kp+1)-f(1)$$

Deduce that $f(kp+1)$ is divisible by $p$, and since $f(kp+1)$ is prime...

Comment: How to show $f(2)=f(1)$ ? In my try ,it is equal to show $\forall p,q$ are primes, there are $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ap=bq+1$.

Comment: @lanse7pty If a polynomial takes one value infinitely many times, it must be constant...You don't need so show that $f(2)=f(1)$, only that $f(x)=p$ has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The notation $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ stands for the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.